Authenticating to Google Doc Translate API
I am having a terrible time trying to authenticate to Google Document Translation API. This API does not accept an API key. Oddly, it seems to require you to provide a file path for a json file as a string to os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]. I have the json file from my enterprise account, but it seems very insecure to have a bunch of secrets sitting in a file next to my code. So I have tried to find other ways to authenticate. One way I saw in a comment on stack overflow was this approach. Basically, you take each of the secrets in the .json file, load it as a secret the normal way you would handle secrets, then package them up in a dictionary and store those to a variable called credentials. When I run this, it says, "google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Your default credentials were not found."
Is there a step I am missing here?  Do I need to somehow pass the "credentials" variable to something else?
I know I cannot simply pass the "credentials" variable to os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] because that will only accept a file path structured as a string.
Any help would be appreciated.
   project_id = REDACTED
   file_path  = REDACTED
   target_language = 'en'


    my_google_credentials = {
        "type": os.environ.get('TYPE'),
        "project_id": os.environ.get('PROJECT_ID'),
        "private_key_id": os.environ.get('PRIVATE_KEY_ID'),
        "private_key":  os.environ.get['private_key'],
        "universe_domain": os.environ.get('UNIVERSE_DOMAIN'),
        "token_uri": os.environ.get('TOKEN_URI'),
        "client_email": os.environ.get('CLIENT_EMAIL'),
        "client_id": os.environ.get('CLIENT_ID'),
        "auth_uri": os.environ.get('AUTH_URI'),
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": os.environ.get('AUTH_PROVIDER_x509_CERT_URL'),
        "client_x509_cert_url": os.environ.get('CLIENT_x509_CERT_URL')
    }

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(my_google_credentials)
    #scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

    response = translate_document(project_id, file_path, target_language)
    print("Translation completed.")



The documentation for authentication for Cloud Translate is comprehensive. I encourage you to review that to understand how authentication can be implemented.

I did review the documentation and I can get the version that relies on a .json file to work.  The problem is that it's not acceptable from a security perspective to just have a file with my keys sitting in the file structure.  Thus, I am trying to see if there is a way to store the elements of the json as secrets which then get accessed via environment variables, combined into a .json and fed to "something" that Google will accept.

How will you authenticate access to the Secrets? It's turtles all the way down. I'm not being difficult by referencing the documentation; I'm saving time by not reiterating the documentation. Those are your choices for a secure approach.

I finally found what works.  You create a translate "client" and then pass the credentials to that client.
from google.cloud import translate_v3beta1 as translate
client = translate.TranslationServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

Then you can access the translate_document method of client.
